# Generic typeof for weak self references

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I am trying to figure out a way to use `typeof` to create a weak reference to `self` for use in blocks to avoid retain cycles.

When I first read about this it seems that the convention was to use `__block typeof(self) bself = self;`, which compiles but using `__block` to avoid retain cycles doesn't work anymore and `__weak` should be used instead.

However `__weak typeof(self) bself = self;` results in an error:

**The type 'typeof (self)' (aka 'TUAccountsViewController *const __strong') already has retainment attributes set on it**

Is there a way to use `typeof` or another call to generically create a weak reference to `self`?

Comment: What's the motivation for using typeof to determine the type, instead of just using the class (TUAccountsViewController) name explicitly?

Comment: I want to make a generic define that can work for whatever the current instance of self is. It all started from this commit and discussion: https://github.com/kgn/BBlock/commit/14ccc46830ea29dec50408a5bd7a17e247b72c20

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This works!

```
__typeof__(o) __weak
```

Which I've defined in my BBlock project as `BBlockWeakSelf` which can be used like this:

```
BBlockWeakSelf wself = self;
```

https://github.com/kgn/BBlock/blob/master/BBlock.h

*Edited based on Aleph7's response.*

Comment: This is the right way of doing it: `__typeof__(self) __weak wself = self;` Note that having __weak before the type is ["technically incorrect"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: keegan3d: Could you edit your answer to reflect Alephs comment? What he says is correct.

Answer (score 37):

In the latest clang version *Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.1.48) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)*, i.e. **Xcode 4.4+**, the `__typeof__((__typeof__(self))self)` trick is not necessary anymore. The `__weak typeof(self) bself = self;` line will compile just fine.

Comment: Hmmm - I just found I needed "_ _ typeof(self) _ _" (minus the spaces) in Xcode 4.6.1

Answer (score 18):

The correct way to do this is

```
__weak ActualClassName* weakSelf = self;
```

Macros only make it unclear what the variable actually is, and what you're actually doing with it, in addition to adding non-portable meta-language to your code.

If you need a more generic version of the class than ActualClassName provides, you aren't dealing with `self` anymore, since where `self` is defined, so is the class of `self` defined.

In those cases, you should use the closest base class name in your inheritance tree, `NSObject` or better, never `id`, e.g.

```
__weak MyBaseClassName* weakObject = object;
```

Answer (score 16):

### Generic Weakself Reference (No Import Required + Snippet)

---

In my experience, the way to go is to use:

`__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;`

[Note how the ownership qualifier belongs in front of the actual variable.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4)

It's very apparent what's happening when it is used and it can be made into a handy code snippet in Xcode which makes it even easier to use in any project or class where this is needed. (I use "ws" as the snippet's completion shortcut)

Hmm.. I need a weak reference here..

`ws{return}`

Done. No need to ever include a header in future projects for this, just use the snippet.

---

### Xcode Snippet

---

Title: `Generic Weak Self Reference`
Platform: `All`
Language: `Objective-C`
Completion Shortcut: `ws`
Completion Scopes: `Function or Method`
Code: `__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;`

---

***Edit: Added note about ownership qualifier position based on [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892361/generic-typeof-for-weak-self-references/19168549#comment33150508_19168549), and Xcode Snippet Info***

Comment: The ownership qualifier belongs in front of the actual variable. You can see this in any of the latest Apple Documentation.    
for example:

MyClass * __weak myWeakReference;
MyClass * __unsafe_unretained myUnsafeReference;

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @SteveM Correct. Most people don't realize this because the compiler "forgives" that transgression. In this example we have `TYPE | OWNERSHIP | VARIABLE NAME = VALUE;`

Answer (score 3):

why don't just use

```
__weak id bself = self;
```

Comment: I thought about that but a cast would still be needed to access any properties on the object, for example: `Property 'isAddingAccount' not found on object of type '__weak id const'`

Comment: or if your objects have something in common declare protocol with this property and declare __weak id <YourProtocol> bself = self;

Comment: These are all good suggestions, just not as generic as I was hoping for. But what I want may not exist...

Answer (score 3):

i think use this to be ok:

__weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self;

it reference AFNetworking's AFURLConnectionOperation.m codes.

Comment: It's ok, and is further-backwards-compatible for older clang versions, but indexing can't help you whereas @Brane's suggestion above will show you callers/callees. If you aren't building a github library, I'd go that route instead.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try check the C Language Dialect?

Go to Project Navigator -> Project -> Target -> Build Settings

There look for C Language Dialect. Change it from c11 to GNU99.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

declareBlockSafe( self ) then blk( self ) inside the block. Self can be any variable or instance variable. Use declareBlockSafeAs for properties and method returns.

Also works with non-ARC if you import Mike Ash's splendid MAZeroingWeakRef.
https://github.com/mikeash/MAZeroingWeakRef

`#if __has_feature(objc_arc)`

```
#define declareBlockSafe(__obj__) __weak typeof(__obj__) __tmpblk##__obj__ = __obj__
#define blockSafe(__obj__) __tmpblk##__obj__
#define blk(__obj__) blockSafe(__obj__)

#define declareBlockSafeAs(__obj__, __name__) \
__weak typeof((__obj__)) __tmpblk##__name__ = (__obj__)

#else

#define declareBlockSafe(__obj__) MAZeroingWeakRef *__tmpblk##__obj__ = [MAZeroingWeakRef refWithTarget:__obj__]
#define blockSafe(__obj__) ((typeof(__obj__))__tmpblk##__obj__##.target)
#define blk(__obj__) blockSafe(__obj__)

#define declareBlockSafeAs(__obj__, __name__) \
MAZeroingWeakRef *__tmpblk##__name__ = (__obj__)
#endif
```

You don't REALLY need blk() for ARC, it's just so that the macros can be used in the same way for non-ARC.

Answer (score 1):

I have this macro

```
#define weaken(object) __typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = object
```

And i use it like this

```
weaken(self);
//The block referencing weakSelf goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

What about __unsafe_unretained? That's not as safe as __weak but it's the only thing I could think of. Also, why do you use typeof()?

Comment: I want to make a generic `define` that can work for whatever the current instance of `self` is. It all started from this commit and discussion: https://github.com/kgn/BBlock/commit/14ccc46830ea29dec50408a5bd7a17e247b72c20

Comment: Unfortunately `__unsafe_unretained` yields the same error: **The type 'typeof (self)' (aka 'TUAccountsViewController *const __strong') already has retainment attributes set on it**

Comment: Does this work in a category of NSObject? -(instancetype)weakReference {
    __weak id obj = self;
    return obj;
}

Comment: That appears to do the trick! My define looks like this: `#define BBlockWeakSelf __weak typeof([self weakReference])` and it's used like this: `BBlockWeakSelf wself = self;`. Full code here: https://github.com/kgn/BBlock/commit/195f6289092ac31e9b50c45e3457fade446eec5b

Comment: This works in debug but when doing an archive release this error occurs: `4. Running pass 'Aggressive Dead Code Elimination' on function '@"\01-[NSObject(BBlockWeakReference) weakReference]"'`. Full Error: http://cl.ly/102r1D1b0x4304240c3X

Comment: This seems to do the trick and it archives: `#define BBlockWeakSelf __weak typeof((typeof(self))self)`. Lemme know if you see any problems with this.