# Objective-C weakself declaration

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

I was looking through some Apple sample code for their 2014 WWDC session 'Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views' and came across a weakself declaration that looked like the following:

```
__weak typeof(&*self) weakself = self;
```

My question is: what do the *&** mean in the declaration? Why not just have:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bikram990 how would it increment retain count? just assigning to a weak reference? Can you explain it in more detail? I don't see how it's possible

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892361/generic-typeof-for-weak-self-references

Comment: @AndreyChernukha My mistake forgot that `__weak` just assigns the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why not just have:
>
> __weak typeof(self) weakself = self;

You can. This is the normal way to do it. Some previous version of the compiler didn't handle it properly, but that was fixed a long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

`self` is a `MyInstance *`. When you say `*self`, you're dereferencing the `self*` getting back `self`. Then when you take the `&(*self)` you're grabbing the memory address.