# Why does using typeof() to create a weak reference does not require a pointer asterisk?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, typeof, variable-types

I was searching a bit about the difference between `__weak` and `__block`

- [What is the difference between a __weak and a __block reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773342/what-the-difference-between-weak-and-block-reference)
- [To ARC or not to ARC? What are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760431/to-arc-or-not-to-arc-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

  and found that if I am using ARC, I should use `__weak` references in blocks.

My old code was something like this:

```
__block GWTSDemandContactsController *safeMe = self;

[GWTSService getSuggestedContactsForDemand:self.demand success:^(NSArray *contacts) {
    safeMe.activityLoading.hidden = true;
    [safeMe setContactsForView:contacts];
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    safeMe.activityLoading.hidden = true;
}];
```

Then when I migrated to use ARC, I started using `__weak` and also found out that I could use `typeof(self)`

- [Generic typeof for weak self references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892361/generic-typeof-for-weak-self-references)

This is very simple, so that I don't have to write the name of the class every time I want to save the `self` reference. So now my code looks like this:

```
__weak typeof(self) safeMe = self;
```

But why do we avoid the `*` here? Shouldn't it be a reference to `self`? What are we storing here by avoiding the `*`?

I don't know if I am missing something or not, but I could not understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the ownership specifiers. It's just that `typeof(self)` is already a pointer, because `self`'s type is "pointer to GWTSDemandContactsController", i.e., `GWTSDemandContactsController *`. The fully-written-out type includes the `*`.

The object *pointed to* is a `GWTSDemandContactsController`, but the variable `self` is a pointer to that object.

Comment: Thank you, nice explanation! I think I understood it. So `typeof(self)` is like writing `GWTSDemandContactsController *` (with the `*` included)? That's what you mean right?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe it was so easy !