# How to declare a weakSelf object in iOS

Tags: ios, block

What's the difference between:

`__weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self`

and

`__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self`

anyone know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 0xced's answer:

> In the latest clang version Apple clang version 4.0
>   (tags/Apple/clang-421.1.48) (based on LLVM 3.1svn), i.e. Xcode 4.4+,
>   the `__typeof__((__typeof__(self))self)` trick is not necessary
>   anymore. The `__weak typeof(self) bself = self;` line will compile
>   just fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11226768/630195